# How to extend life of JWT Token Issued from IdentityServer 3

Tags: c#, jwt, identityserver3

I am trying to setup an IdentityServer 3 web application not hardware, this is a software development related question.  I am trying to learn how to use the technology and produce JWT token's that my api can consume.  The problem is I cannot for the life of me find where to set the token expiration.  It always produces a 401 after about an hour.  Ideally for testing purposes I would like to extend this to a very long time so I do not have to keep copy and pasting my JWT token into fiddler thus dramatically slowing down my development and learning process.

**My Client**

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "scheduling"
                ,ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                {
                    new Secret("65A6A6C3-A764-41D9-9D10-FC09E0DBB046".Sha256())
                },
                ClientName = "Patient Scheduling",
                Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    Constants.StandardScopes.OfflineAccess,
                    "read",
                    "adprofile",
                    "scheduling"
                },
                Enabled = true
            }
```

**My Scope**

```
   new Scope
            {
                Name = "scheduling",
                Claims = new List<ScopeClaim>
                {
                     new ScopeClaim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Role,true),
                     new ScopeClaim("scheduling_id",true),
                     new ScopeClaim("expires_at",true)  //I have tried "expires_in" and [Constants.ClaimTypes.Expiration] also with no luck
                }
            }
```

**Method used for client specific claims:**

```
  private IEnumerable<Claim> GetClaimByClientId(string client_id)
    {
        List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>();
        switch(client_id.ToLower())
        {
            case "scheduling":
                claims = new List<Claim>();
                claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,"administrator"));
                claims.Add(new Claim("scheduling_id", "2"));
                //claims.Add(new Claim("expires_in", "2082758400")); //01/01/2036
                //claims.Add(new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Expiration, "2082758400")); //01/01/2036
                claims.Add(new Claim("expires_at", "2082758400")); //01/01/2036
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("Client not found with provided client id.");
        }


        return claims;
    }
```

**Code actually validating Credentials:**

```
            if (ActiveDirectoryHelper.ValidateCredentials(context.UserName, context.Password, adName))
            {

                List<Claim> lstClaims = new List<Claim>
                {
                    new Claim("obj_id",user.UserID.ToUpper()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.Email, string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Email) ? string.Empty : user.Email.ToLower()),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,user.FirstName),
                    new Claim(Constants.ClaimTypes.FamilyName,user.LastName),
                    new Claim("EmployeeNumber",user.EmployeeNumber),


                };

                lstClaims.AddRange(GetClaimByClientId("scheduling"));


                context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult(user.UserID,user.Username, lstClaims);
            }
            else
            {
                context.AuthenticateResult = new AuthenticateResult("Invalid Login.");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access Token lifetime (I assume this is what you mean by JWT token) can be set for a client application using the [`Client`](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/clients.html) property `AccessTokenLifetime`.

By default this is set to 3600 seconds (1 hour).

Comment: Thank you and I researched the AccesTokenLifetime which then took me to the documentation. Thank you very much.